# Tengo este método post, donde se registra un paciente a partir de los datos introducidos, pero no se me introduce en la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql, api

Este es el código que tengo. He puesto el if para que esos  campos tengan que tener datos al introducirlos en la base de datos.
Al hacer la connection se me va directamente al "if (err)" y no se me introduce en la base de datos.
¿Cómo lo podrías solucionar?

```
app.post("/api/paciente", function (req, res) {
    if (req.body.nombre == "" || req.body.apellidos == "" || req.body.login == "" || req.body.password == "" ){
        return res.status(403).send(" (faltan datos");
    }
    var sql = "INSERT INTO paciente (nombre, apellidos, fecha_nacimiento, genero, login, password,cuidador, personal)" + 
    " VALUES ('"+req.body.nombre +"','"+req.body.apellidos +"','"+req.body.fecha_nacimiento +"','"+req.body.genero +"','"+req.body.login+"','"+req.body.password +"','"+req.body.cuidador +"','"+req.body.personal+"')";
    connection.query(sql, function(err, paciente){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
            res.status(403).send("No se ha podido registrar ");
            return;
        }
        return res.status(201).json(paciente);
    });
});
```

Comment: ¿Y que error te da el console.log(err)?

Comment: Cuál es el SQL resultante? es decir, luego que armas la query (vulnerable a SQL Injection, por cierto), qué es lo que se manda a la base de datos? Por cierto el código de respuesta 403 corresponde a Forbidden. En caso de que falten datos, u ocurra un error porque faltan datos, entonces lo más adecuado, IMO, es un [400 - Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Comment: Lo que me devuelve el console.log(err) es la sentencia sql con los datos introducidos.  He probado a meter todos los campos y si que me introduce, pero al poner solo los obligatorios se me va directamente al if(err). Si, la sintaxis no es la más adecuada, la cambiaré, gracias